How to configure Elastic.Serilog.Sinks 8.11 in ASP.NET Core 8 web app?
I used Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch 10.0 package but it has been deprecated now. But I don't how to configure recommended package Elastic.Serilog.Sinks 8.11. Please help me.
Current code:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(Configuration["ElasticPath"]))
    {
        ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication("username", "password"),
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv8,
        IndexFormat = $"projectx-{Configuration["Environment"]}-{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM}",
        BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
        TypeName = null,
        FailureCallback = (e, ex) => Console.WriteLine("Unable to submit event " + e.MessageTemplate),
        EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                         EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                         EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback
    })
    .CreateLogger();

This sample code block but I didn't set authentication and index name:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .MinimumLevel.Debug()
     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     .WriteTo.Console(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
     .WriteTo.Elasticsearch([new Uri(Configuration["ElasticPath"])], opts =>
                {
                    opts.BootstrapMethod = Elastic.Ingest.Elasticsearch.BootstrapMethod.Failure;
                    opts.DataStream = new Elastic.Ingest.Elasticsearch.DataStreams.DataStreamName("logs", "generic");
                    opts.ConfigureChannel = channelOpts => {
                        channelOpts.BufferOptions = new BufferOptions { ExportMaxConcurrency = 10 };                        
                    };
                })
     .CreateLogger();


To add authentication like before, you can do this way :
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
 .MinimumLevel.Debug()
 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .WriteTo.Console(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
 .WriteTo.Elasticsearch([new Uri(Configuration["ElasticPath"])], opts =>
 {
     opts.BootstrapMethod = Elastic.Ingest.Elasticsearch.BootstrapMethod.Failure;
     opts.DataStream = new Elastic.Ingest.Elasticsearch.DataStreams.DataStreamName("logs", "generic");
     opts.ConfigureChannel = channelOpts => {
         channelOpts.BufferOptions = new BufferOptions { ExportMaxConcurrency = 10 };
     };
 }, transport =>
 {
    transport.Authentication(new BasicAuthentication(username, password));
 })
 .CreateLogger();


In my project we use Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch and since it's deprecated I set out to migrate to Elastic.Serilog.Sinks.
I ended up searching alot for information how to do this.
After some time I've realized there are differences how data is pushed. The new elastic sink uses ILM and datastreams instead of just indices.
So I thought I'd share some info
my csproj contains the following packages
<PackageReference Include="Elastic.Serilog.Sinks" Version="8.12.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" Version="2.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch" Version="8.15.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Elastic.CommonSchema.Serilog" Version="8.12.1" />

and my appsettings looks like this:
{
  "Environment": "dev",
  "serilog:nodeUris": "http://localhost:9200",
  "serilog:basicAuthUsername": "elastic",
  "serilog:basicAuthPassword": "testtest",
  "serilog:MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
  "serilog:IlmPolicy": "my-Policy"
}

my program.cs contain these 2 important lines
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Host.AddSerilogging(builder.Configuration);

and my serilog config contains this:
public static class SerilogConfiguration
{
    public static void AddSerilogging(this IHostBuilder host, IConfiguration config)
    {
        host.UseSerilog((context, loggerconfig) =>
        {
            var configurationsBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("apssettings.json", true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var env = config.GetValue<string>("Environment");
            var ilmPolicy = config.GetValue<string>("serilog:IlmPolicy");

            var nodeUriString = config.GetValue<string>("serilog:nodeUris");
            var nodeUris = nodeUriString.Split(',')
                .Select(uri => new Uri(uri))
                .ToList();

            var basicAuthUsername = config.GetValue<string>("serilog:basicAuthUsername");
            var basicAuthPassword = config.GetValue<string>("serilog:basicAuthPassword");

            Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel minimumloglevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error;
            if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel), config.GetValue<string>("serilog:MinimumLevel"), out var x))
            {
                minimumloglevel = (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)x;
            }

            var appName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

            // Setup the Serilog sink
            loggerconfig
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File(
                    new JsonFormatter(),
                    @$"C:\\inetpub\\log\\apps\\{appName}-.txt",
                    minimumloglevel,
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", minimumloglevel)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", env)
                .Enrich.WithRequestHeader("Authentication")
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
                bootstrapMethod: Elastic.Ingest.Elasticsearch.BootstrapMethod.Silent,
                dataStream: $@"icc-{env}-{appName}",
                username: basicAuthUsername,
                password: basicAuthPassword,
                nodes: nodeUris,
                ilmPolicy: ilmPolicy);

        });
    }
}

Now if someone else would've written something like this before it would've helped me alot. Hope this helps someone in the future migrating.
